# Zend_Framework 1.12 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

Before anything I am aware of the multiple questions asked concerning this exception. I have looked through them but have not found an answer for my particular problem. Most of the questions use the `Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();` , and I am not using that. Instead I am using an `Application_Model_DbTable_Name` and am left wondering if it´s possible to do so.

Also, I do have access since that´s the first thing I checked when I saw the error. The database is local and I access it with the same user/password through MySqlWorkBench.

My goal is to delete **a row** when two columns meet the criteria set in the controller action, like so:

```
public function deleteAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $this->_validateDigit($request->getParam('id'));
        // _validateDigit(..) checks that the variable is numeric and if it´s not it redirects to 
        // an error page

        $db = new Application_Model_DbTable_BecasPerfiles();
        $select = $db->select();
        $select->where('unidad=?', $this->_getUnit())
                ->where('id=?', (int) $request->getParam('id'));

        $db->delete($select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE));
        $this->_redirect('/profile/view-profiles/unit/'.$this->_getUnit());
    }

 private function _getUnit()
    {
        return Zend_Registry::getInstance()['session']->unit;
                  //unit is nothing but a string
    }
```

Here is my DbTable class (real simple):

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_BecasPerfiles extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'becas_perfiles';

}
```

Here is the error that spits out:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to  use near 'AND (id=7))' at line 1
```

Here is what calls my attention **AND (id=7))**, see the extra parenthesis? where is that coming from?

Here is the result of `var_dump($select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE));`

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(33) "(unidad='Galería de Arte ULPGC')" [1]=> string(10) "AND (id=7)" }
```

Just for the fun of it, I tried switching the order of the where clause:

```
$select->where('id=?', (int) $request->getParam('id'))
        ->where('unidad=?', $this->_getUnit());
```

Here is the output:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: ...
 syntax to use near 'AND (unidad='Galería de Arte ULPGC'))' at line 1
```

There it is again, *AND (unidad='Galería de Arte ULPGC')**)*** that second parenthesis. I don´t really know if that´s the problem (but I figure it is because otherwise I don´t know what could posssibly be wrong).

I tried just using one where condition (like id), and it deleted just fine. I´d really appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is a mismatch between what `getPart()` returns and what `delete()` expects.

As you already pointed out, `var_dump($select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE));` also returns the logical operators in the where statement, but the `delete()` operator either expects an array in the form "field => value" or a string containing the full where clause.

So the simplest (untested) approach to fix your problem would be to pass `$db->delete(implode(' ', $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)));` so that `delete()` receives a fully qualified where clause as string instead of an array it cannot handle.